# get at instance variable from inside constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Hi Im having this problem that when Im creating a class in coffeescript I want to define a function on an object in the contructor, but I cant figure out the scope, see the code example belove

```
collection_of_objects = [{id:234},{id:546},{id:234}]

class SampleObject
  constructor: (collection_of_objects)->
    @posts = []
    @divide_number = 1337
    for post in collection_of_objects
      post.magicnr = ()->
        return @id / @divide_number
```

the id get set but I cant get at divide_number from inside the magicnr function
i realize its due to the scope, but I cant seem to figure out how to do it
i tried to make a getDivideNumber function that returns it but I cant seem to access that inside the magicnr function either

any help would be appreciated

UPDATE
Had to settle for the following hack

```
collection_of_objects = [{id:234},{id:546},{id:234}]

class SampleObject
  @divide_number = 1337
  divide_number = @divide_number
  constructor: (collection_of_objects)->
    @posts = []
    for post in collection_of_objects
      post.magicnr = ()->
        return @id / divide_number
  # for updating the @divide_number
  setDivnr: (nr)->
    @divide_number = nr
    divide_number = @divide_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you are defining magicnr you change scope. this (@) becomes post.

You can get round this either by caching a reference to @divide_number:

```
for post in collection_of_objects
  divide_number = @divide_number
  post.magicnr = ()->
    return @id / divide_number
```

or by using a fat arrow to define post.magicnr like this:

```
for post in collection_of_objects
  post.magicnr = ()=>
    return post.id / @divide_number
```

Comment: caching a reference to "@divide_number" would not work since the "@divide_number" could change and the post.magicnr needs to reflect this change.. 
the "fat arrow" solution does not seem to work at all, doesent find "@id" or "@divide_number"

Comment: divide_number = \@divide_number could be called each time \@divide_number changes. ahh ofc fat arrow approach would mean you have to reference @id via post.id (sorry). Ill update my answer for you :)

Comment: yeah, thanks, I think I have to go with the calling the divide_number = \@divide_number each time total is changed, because with the fat arrow and post.id it refrences the last of the posts in all cases.. thanks for you help :)

Comment: no problem! im glad to help :) just a quick note... divide_number = \@divide_number should read divide_number = @divide_number (no backslash) these slashes went into the comment as stack overflow thought i was trying to notify a user called divide_number of the post